# Absolute integrability of L2 function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I need to show that dilation operator $D_c$ is well-defined from $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. I have to show that
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |D_cf(x)|^2 dx < \infty$ for $$f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$$
The dilation operator is defined as
$$(D_cf)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}f(x/c)\ \text{for}\ c>0\ \text{and}\ x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

My question is, does the following hold:
$$\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty D_cf(x) dx \right|^2 \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |D_cf(x)|^2 dx,$$
just like this holds:
$$\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty D_cf(x) dx \right| \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |D_cf(x)| dx.$$

Comment: What does $D_c$ exactly do?

Comment: I have edited the question, such that it is included - thank you for your comment :)

Comment: The desired inequality is false, in general, without reference to the dilation operator, because, for example,  $(1+1)^2>1^2+1^2$. But, happily, you do not _need_ that inequality.